# Moodle login through Google Authentication (SSO)

Tags: integration, single-sign-on, google-apps, moodle

Our school is starting to use Moodle for our LMS service.  We also currently use Google apps.  Is there a way to sync the users from Google Apps to moodle.  We need the user creation to happen through Google Apps and if the user changes the password in Apps they still are able to authenticate into Moodle.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin that does that :)

https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=auth_googleoauth2